# cp: cannot stat 'ls -l ~/ | grep ^.r\w\-': No such file or directory - error

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I have been trying to copy all files with read/write permissions for owners from the home directory to another directory but I've been facing this problem as in the title.
Any help?

```
subDir=`date '+%y%m%d%H%M%S'`
mkdir $subDir
cp -R 'ls -l ~/ | grep ^.r\w\-' $subDir
chmod -wx $subDir/*
```

Comment: @WilliamPursell that was a markdown formatting typo that was fixed with an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not parse ls. To find files use `find`.

```
find . -type f -perm -u=rw -exec cp {} "$subDir" ';'
# Faster:
... -exec cp -t "$subDir" {} +
```

I *think* you want `find ~ -maxdepth 1`, I do not know if recursive files or not.